# Good game programming books

Tags: video

Does anyone know of any good books for video game programming? I don't care what programming language, but I would prefer C++. I would prefer it not be specific to DirectX or openGL if possible. It would also be nice if it explained programming for 2D games.
I would also like 3D design book suggestion.

Edit: Ran through a Google search, a few people suggested the "Game Gems" books. Does anyone know if these are good?

Comment: For game development questions specifically, use the GameDev stackexchange: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1265/must-read-game-development-books

Answer (score 0):

Although it might be a bit dated The Game Maker Manual. It's freeware stuff but it helps out with the basic concepts.

I've used Game Maker for the framework for most of my games and it is the most useful/easy to use tool I've ever came across.